# Bladder size based on child height/weight

Tags: human-biology

My son is 10 years old, but weighs 24kg, which is quite little for his age.

Is it correct to estimate his bladder volume based on a formula using age? This seems to be a generally accepted way, for example: (age + 1) * 30 = volume in ml.

I would assume that a smaller and thinner child will also have a smaller bladder?

Comment: Obviously there are more factors involved than just age. But age is easy to use even if it's wrong. Very much like how BMI ignores a bunch of other stuff about people.

Comment: May I ask why you are asking this question? There are studies that answer this, and it's most important in the pediatric population because of kids with urinary tract issues. At which point is it related to height more than weight? Because obviously it's not linear.

Comment: **Personal medical questions and health advice** are off-topic on Biology.SE. We cannot safely answer questions for your specific situation and you should **always consult a doctor for medical advice**.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I'm asking to be able to discuss further with a urologist. I'm not convinced with their judgement by age, because my son is in the lowest 10 percentiles for weight and in the lowest 25 for height his age. Nonetheless, she is convinced this does not matter for his bladder size and required volumes. I'm not looking for a big discussion, but it did make me wonder if there are studies saying otherwise.

Comment: Ah, in that case, it's personal medical advice, but it's easy enough to Google, esp. if you use Google Scholar.

Comment: Well, I'm not looking for advice actually, just wondering. Because, I'd assume, smaller body, smaller organs, larger body, larger organs. I'm wondering if my assumption is correct. I did come across these studies yesterday, but I don't know enough about the subject to be able to interpret correctly: https://www.academia.edu/resource/work/12317425, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2062747/

Comment: So, to clarify further, I'm obviously consulting a doctor for this, and won't use any answers as medical advice. I'm just wondering, as an outsider, if organs are larger in larger children of the same age?